# Problema com codificação no phpmyadmin em servidor remoto

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, codificação-de-caracteres, utf-8, collection

O problema é o seguinte.

Estou desenvolvendo um site localmente em PHP com acesso a banco de dados e estou enfrentando problemas de codificação, mas este problema só acontece na hospedagem, funciona normalmente no servidor local.

Palavras com acentuação ficam com "�"(?) mas apenas para os dados que vem do banco de dados.

No banco de dados todas as acentuações são apresentadas corretamente.

Estou como meus arquivos codificados em UTF-8.

As minhas paginas contem `<meta charset="utf-8">`.

e aparentemente todas as informações de codificação no meu banco de dados também estão em UTF-8 (utf-8_general_ci), da mesma forma que está configurada no servidor local.

ao usar os comandos

```
show variables like '%char%';

show variables like '%coll%';
```

percebi que a única diferença está no `"collation_server"`

o local está `utf8mb4_general_ci`

e o remoto está como `latin1_swedish_ci`

por favor oque está acontecendo no servidor remoto não faço a mínima ideia de como resolver

Comment: Você já tentou mudar a configuração de Encoding do PhpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia pessoal, depois de um bom estudo consegui resolver o problema e para aqueles que tiverem este mesmo problema eu resolvi da seguinte forma:

Existem configurações padrões para conjuntos de caracteres e collations em quatro níveis:

servidor, banco de dados, tabela e conexão.

Cada uma delas tem uma solução diferente, tenha em mente que nos 4 niveis é necessario que contenha a mesma codificação como no caso estou trabalhando com utf-8 eu ultilizarei utf-8 para todos os niveis. vamos fazer algumas verificações basicas:

primeiro verifique a codificação que seu arquivo foi salvo.
isso é encontrado em alguns aditores de código normalmente na parte inferior da aplicação.
como no caso do VScode e do próprio NOTEPAD do windows:

[image: foto da codificação no VScode]

[image: foto da codificação no notepad]

Após esta verificação, vamos para o codigo do arquivo, é muito importante que dentro do arquivo contenha a identificação do tipo de codificação.

existem duas formas de fazer isso:

no HTML dentro do head você pode identificar da seguinte forma

```
<meta charset="utf-8">`
```

como mostra na imagem:

[image: Foto do código charset]

e dentro do PHP no inicio do codigo use:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Dessa forma estabelecemos conexão informando a codificação ultilizada.

Caso isso ainda não tenha resolvido vamos mais a fundo.

Agora será necessario verificar o banco de dados e suas tabelas elas devem estar em UTF-8 ou utf8mb4.

ao abrir o phpmyadmin e acessar a base de dados é possivel ver nas informações das tabelas a codificação ultilizada em cada uma e verificar a codificação da própria base de dados.

[image: codificação da base de dados]

A codificação da própria base de dados é exibida na ultima linha da imagem.

Caso a codificação da base estiver diferente dos niveis acima provavelmente esse é o problema de codificação do seu site.

para resolver basta selecionar a base de dados e clicar em operações no menu superior

[image: operações base de dados]

Ache a opção de Agrupamento (Collation)

[image: Agrupamento (Collation)]

e selecione a codificação correta no menu dropdown
dessa forma a base de dados estará correta, agora é só verificar as tabelas e efetuar o mesmo procedimento em todas as tabelas da base de dados em questão.

selecione a tabela desejada vá para operações e ache a opção de Agrupamento (Collation).

Resolvido ?? se não, como foi no meu caso, agora é mais complicado, ao menos foi pra mim.

Vamos resolver de uma vez por todas.

use no phpmyadmin os seguintes comando:

```
show variables like '%char%';
show variables like '%coll%';
```

O resultado será o mostrado na imagem a seguir, como mostra na imagem a parte circulada o problema estava em

collation_server e character_set_server

onde seus valores incorretos eram:

character_set_server: latin1
collation_server: latin1_swedish_ci

Após corrigir para:

character_set_server: utf8mb4_general_ci
collation_server: utf8mb4_general_ci

como está mostrando na própria imagem o problema foi resolvido.

[image: collation server 1]
[image: collation server 2]

para resolver está configuração acesse o arquivo de configuração do mysql pode ser tanto my.cnf quanto my.ini procure a seção `[mysqld]` e modifique as linhas no meu caso estava

```
character-set-server=latin1
collation-server=latin1_swedish_ci
```

e modifiquei para

```
character-set-server=utf8mb4
collation-server=utf8mb4_general_ci
```

Atenção !! caso este problema esteja acontecendo no servidor externo (hospedagem) provavelmente você não terá acesso a este arquivo de configuração então faça contato com o suporte da hospedagem e solicite a modificação.

Espero ter ajudado, qualquer duvida estou disponivel a ajudar.

Comment: Inclusive, se você precisar utilzar um join e em uma da tabelas o conjunto de caracteres forem de tipos diferentes, isso pode tornar a consulta mais lenta. Recomendo complementar com as informações postadas aqui https://stackoverflow.com/a/38995859/4623423

Comment: me deslcupa, sou um pouco novo na plataforma e estou em dúvida oq eu poderia fazer ?

Comment: Foi apenas uma sugestão para complementar o post (editar e adicionar algumas informações extras) pra enriquecer a postagem. Por exemplo, uma alteração de  nome  de uma coluna, o phpmyadmin vai fazer  pra você o ALTER TABLE xyz  
RENAME COLUMN nome_da_coluna TO novo_nome_coluna; e seria legal ter essas informações. Reforço, é sugestão apenas :)